# How to get the anchor tag value and href value inside a header tag using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My html page code consists alot of anchor tags, but i need to get all the **href value** inside the anchor tag and **anchor tag value** which are present inside a **header tag** of a **div element**, i'm using **selenium in java** to get the page source of the html.

The part of html code of my the webpage look like this :-

```
<a href="www.qq.com">qq</a>
<a href="www.ww.com">ww</a>
<a href="www.ee.com">ee</a>
<div class="hello">
<h2>
<a href="www.aa.com">aa</a>
<a href="www.ss.com">aa</a>
</h2>
<div>
```

The java code i'm using to retrieve the anchor tag values look like this :-

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@href]"));
        for (WebElement e : list) {
            String link = e.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(e.getTagName() + "=" + link);
        }
```

The output of the above code is look like this:-

```
a=www.qq.com
a=www.ww.com
a=www.ee.com
a=www.aa.com
a=www.ss.com
```

But the output i need is like this:-

```
a=www.aa.com , aa
a=www.ss.com , ss
```

I need to get the all the anchortag values and href values inside the **hello class**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -- Use `getText()` and modified xpath to include hrefs inside the div with class hello. Assuming the particular div is the unique one with the class name.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='hello']//a[@href]"));
            for (WebElement e : list) {
                String link = e.getAttribute("href");
                System.out.println(e.getTagName() + "=" + link + " , " + e.getText());
            }
```

Comment: The xpath was missing an @. Edited in answer. Maybe this works.

Comment: Thanx @Grasshopper, its working like a charm! :), i have one doubt, can we use the same process to the anchortag values inside the ul tag?

Comment: Yeah, tried it. Its also working fine, Thanx @Grasshopper, you make my day!! :)